Trying to export a time series of EVI values for a large asset in Google Earth Engine
I'm trying to export a time series of EVI data for a large asset containing 40,000 points. I am using the MODIS data. The code that I've written works when I extract data for 5 points, but it's not going to work for 40,000. Is there a function I could write into the code that would achieve the extraction of all 40,000 points? The code that I am using is this where "table" is my asset with 5 points:
var startDate = '2003-01-01'
var endDate = '2023-01-01'

// A function to mask out pixels that did not have observations.
var maskEmptyPixels = function(image) {
  // Find pixels that had observations.
  var withObs = image.select('EVI').gt(0)
  return image.updateMask(withObs)
}

// A function to mask out cloudy pixels.
var maskClouds = function(image) {
  // Select the QA band.
  var QA = image.select('EVI')
  // Make a mask to get bit 10, the internal_cloud_algorithm_flag bit.
  var bitMask = 1 << 10;
  // Return an image masking out cloudy areas.
  return image.updateMask(QA.bitwiseAnd(bitMask).eq(0))
}
  

var images = modis.filter(ee.Filter.date(startDate,endDate))
.map(maskEmptyPixels)
.map(maskClouds)
//print(images)

// Add scaling to the EVI because it has a scale factor 
var scaling = function(image){
  var scaled = image.select('EVI').divide(10000)
  return scaled.copyProperties(image, ['system:index', 'system:time_start'])
}
var scaled_evi = images.map(scaling)
print(scaled_evi)
var ev = scaled_evi.first()

//seeing how it looks
Map.addLayer(ev, {min:0,max:1,palette:['white','green']}, 'EVI')


//Create a chart with the EVI time series data
var chart = ui.Chart.image.seriesByRegion({
  imageCollection:scaled_evi,
  regions:table,
  reducer:ee.Reducer.mean(),
  scale:250,
  
})
print(chart)```





can you add you export code? A;so better to include the catalog data import too, rather than having people to look for data to reproduce.

https://developers.google.com/earth-engine/guides/reducers_reduce_regions
